# Replicating cfoutput grouping using ORM

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, lucee

I'm converting to Coldfusion's ORM and was wondering how do I replicate cfoutput's grouping using ORM?

I'm getting the following error : `Can't cast Object type [java.util.ArrayList] to a value of type [query]`

Query:

```
qryGames = ormExecuteQuery("from Game where Season.seasonID=:sid and League.leagueID=:lid and Season.User.userID=:uid order by League.leagueName, GameType.gameTypeID, gameDate DESC", {sid=url.sid, lid=leagueID, uid=session.userID});
```

Code:

```
<cfif arraylen(qryGames) GT 0>
    <cfoutput query="qryGames" group="leagueName">
        <cfoutput group="gameTypeName">
            ...
        </cfoutput>
    </cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

I don't see grouping attributes for cfloop. I could always manually replicate this but was wondering if there was a built in way to do it.

**Update #1**

Using `entityToQuery`:

```
qryGames = entityToQuery(ormExecuteQuery("from Game where Season.seasonID=:sid and League.leagueID=:lid and Season.User.userID=:uid order by League.leagueName, GameType.gameTypeID, gameDate DESC", {sid=url.sid, lid=leagueID, uid=session.userID}), "League");
```

I get the following error:

```
Message     column [gameTypeName] not found in query, columns are [leagueID,leagueName,leagueAbbr,teamName,gameInMinutes,deleteYN,showReportYN]
```

Limited to one entity name?

Comment: That missing column name error should be pretty easy to sort out.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm not sure... when I specify an entity, it only gives me the attributes of that one. However, I need attributes from many attributes from many entities when doing the cfoutput grouping (ie. Game.*, League.*, GameType.*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EntityToQuery()` http://cfdocs.org/entitytoquery first, then you can use `<cfoutput query=`

Comment: what happens to relationships? So far, I was able to have one of the two required for the group to work... see update #1

Comment: yes there are limitations, so feel free to drop back to using the good old `<cfquery>`

Comment: they're not not mutually exclusive, so use whatever works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your result set is not a query, but an array, and must be looped over as such.

```
<cfloop array="#games#" index="game">
    <!--- do stuff --->
</cfloop>
```

As far as duplicating the built-in grouping functionality available for queries, I don't believe there is an automatic way with arrays, so you will need to write the logic in your group to perform the grouping or you will need to split the result set up once it is returned and loop over the different parts with separate loops.